# Очистить input-ы автоматом на чистом js после отправки данных функцией

Tags: input

есть элементы input для отправки данных кнопкой по онклику с помощью функции, все работает, но окна этих инпутов после срабатывания функции остаются со старыми данными, как очистить их автоматом по результату?

```
ввод данных:
```

```js
function gen_1(){
 var tel1,fio,res1;
  
  tel1 = document.getElementById('in1').value;
  fio = document.getElementById('in2').value;
  res1 = "fio: " + fio + ", tel: "+ tel1;
  
  document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = res1;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Тел: <input type="text" value="" id="in1"></p>
    <p>ФИО: <input type="text" value="" id="in2"></p>
    <p><button id="gen1" onclick="gen_1()">Записать данные</button></p>
    <p id="out1">***</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("in1").value = "";
document.getElementById("in2").value = "";
```

?

Comment: благодарю,  работает. если можно еще один момент, у меня есть обязательное поле для заполнения с id="in1", как сделать чтобы функция gen_1 выполнилась только после этого условия?

Comment: Лучше всего на самом деле почитать учебник по html/css/javascript (Например: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B), так будет больше понимания, что и как устроено. Если хочется быстро, то заменить `document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = res1;` на: `if (tel1.trim() != '') {
    document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = res1;
   } else {
    alert('Введите номер телефона');
   }`